# No SDKs have been installed yet. Flutter. SDKs installed outside of fvm will not be displayed

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I have been using different flutter versions to build different flutter projects. Using different versions make problems in different projects. So I tried to use [fvm](https://fvm.app/). but it shows

```
No SDKs have been installed yet. Flutter. SDKs installed outside of fvm will not be displayed.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a right answer.

```
fvm install stable or fvm install 2.0.3
```

I have installed the versions which I want.

Now it shows the list of Flutter SDK versions I have downloaded.